# MASM32 How to print out the process id using PROCESSENTRY32

Tags: assembly, masm, msdn, masm32

I'm working on a program and having trouble printing out the process id of the process. I have successfully retrieved the name of the process but when I'm printing out the Process ID. It's showing up all the same. Below is my code.

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
  cFmt db "%d",0
  cfr db 1024 dup(?)

.code
ProcessSearch proc
LOCAL sHndl :DWORD

  push 0
  push TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS
  call CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

  mov sHndl, eax

  mov pData.dwSize, sizeof pData

  push offset pData
  push sHndl
  call Process32First

  push offset pData
  push sHndl
  call Process32Next

  process:

    push offset pData.th32ProcessID
    push offset cFmt
    push offset cfr
    call wsprintf

    push offset cfr
    call StdOut

    push offset pData
    push sHndl
    call Process32Next
    cmp eax, 0
    jg process

  push sHndl
  call CloseHandle

  ret

    ProcessSearch endp
start:
      call ProcessSearch
      call ExitProcess
end start
```

I can't figure out why I can't print the process id.

Comment: Even if we wanted to, we couldn't debug this code for you because it does not represent a [mcve]. What are `cFmt` and `cfr`, for example? It also isn't clear what is meant by, *"It's showing up all the same."* Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and see where it's going astray? Visual Studio includes an excellent debugger. Or there is in WinDbg included for free with the SDK. Not sure if MASM32 ships with a debugger; it probably does, you can't do assembly development without one!

Comment: Since you're using masm, why aren't you using `invoke` instead of `push/call`? That would simplify the code a lot.

Comment: I have updated the code with the repsective values of cFmt and cfr. I'm well aware of how invoke can simplify my code. However, I needed to practice this kind of coding style for the basics.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you showed us the full code so we could verify that your strings/data is correct. Even without that I can see some problems:

`Process32First` retrieves data for the first process, you need to 1) check the return value, and 2) print out the data, before calling `Process32Next`.

`wsprintf` is not stdcall, you should probably restore the stack with something like `lea esp,[esp+12]` after calling it.

Comment: When I use stdout in my program. It doesn't output what I wanted it to output. However, using wsprintf I can specify what type of data I'm expecting. I believe that it is a DWORD but I still can't figure out how it is done.